# Is there a redo function for Lotus Notes 8.5? If not, why isn't there one?

Tags: lotus-notes, lotus-symphony

I am completely exasperated as to why you would write software with an undo function but no option to redo...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you asking a question, or just complaining? Notes only has UNDO which is control-z, Symphony has UNDO and REDO which are control-z and control-y respectively. As I'm sure you're aware since the options are under the Edit menu, just like in most programs.

Comment: Are you answering, or just commenting?

Comment: Is that better?

Comment: uhuhuhuhuhuhuh :)

Comment: well abit of both, this makes me hate notes and IBM even more.